# How to smooth z values and reduce its variation in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, pca, smoothing

I have a 3D point cloud file containing x, y,z values. My ultimate goal is to cluster the point cloud. But the point cloud had some noise and I removed the noise using PCA. Now I want to smoothen the z values and cluster it based on the x and y.
I know the smoothing can be done using "gridfit" in matlab, (gridfit.m) but I am looking for a solution that can be done in Python.
https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit
Is there a method that works similar to gridfit for reducing the variation of z?

Answer (score 0):

this function is open source, it take some time to convert it but it is not impossible.

You just need theses functions:

```
def histc(X, bins):
    map_to_bins = numpy.digitize(X,bins)
    r = numpy.zeros(bins.shape)
    for i in map_to_bins:
        r[i-1] += 1
    return r, map_to_bins
    
def sparse(i, j, v, m, n):
    """
    Create and compressing a matrix that have many zeros
    Parameters:
        i: 1-D array representing the index 1 values 
            Size n1
        j: 1-D array representing the index 2 values 
            Size n1
        v: 1-D array representing the values 
            Size n1
        m: integer representing x size of the matrix
        n: integer representing y size of the matrix
    Returns:
        s: 2-D array
            Matrix full of zeros excepting values v at indexes i, j
    """
    return scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((v, (i, j)), shape=(m, n))

def repmat(A, reps):
    """
    Repeting A list according to list dimension
    Parameters:
        A: array_like
            The input array.
        reps: array_like
            The number of repetitions of A along each axis.
    Returns:
        c: ndarray
            The tiled output array.
    """
    return numpy.tile(A, numpy.array(reps))

def meshgrid(a, b):
    """
    Return coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors.
    Make N-D coordinate arrays for vectorized evaluations 
    of N-D scalar/vector fields over N-D grids, 
    given one-dimensional coordinate arrays a, b
    Parameters:
        a: array_like
            1-D arrays representing the x coordinates of a grid.
        b: array_like
            1-D arrays representing the y coordinates of a grid.
    Returns:
        c: 2-D arrays representing the x * ycoordinates of grid.
    """
    return numpy.meshgrid(a, b)
```

Otherwise you can use griddata and apply a blur on it by considering the result as an grayscale image but don't forget to cut off edges to avoid sharp edges:
[image: Grid data with shap eges]
[image: Grid fit with smooth edges]

You have the [mathematical description here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwilgdDP_bHsAhUmxoUKHaFqCv8QFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsvn.oss.deltares.nl%2Frepos%2Fopenearthtools%2Ftrunk%2Fmatlab%2Fgeneral%2Fgrid_fun%2Fprivate%2Fgridfit%2Fdoc%2Fgridfit.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2fgMEPd4V1Ry1DAUgivvha).

Don't forget to [checkout source code here.](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit)

Here is the default parameter code in matlab to translate:

```
function [zgrid,xgrid,ygrid] = gridfit(x,y,z,xnodes,ynodes,varargin)

params.smoothness = 1;
params.interp = 'triangle';
params.regularizer = 'gradient';
params.solver = 'backslash';
params.maxiter = [];
params.extend = 'warning';
params.tilesize = inf;
params.overlap = 0.20;
params.mask = []; 
params.autoscale = 'on';
params.xscale = 1;
params.yscale = 1;
params = check_params(params);
xmin = min(x);
xmax = max(x);
ymin = min(y);
ymax = max(y);


xnodes=xnodes(:);
ynodes=ynodes(:);
dx = diff(xnodes);
dy = diff(ynodes);
nx = length(xnodes);
ny = length(ynodes);
ngrid = nx*ny;

params.xscale = mean(dx);
params.yscale = mean(dy);


n = length(x);

[junk,indx] = histc(x,xnodes);
[junk,indy] = histc(y,ynodes);
k=(indx==nx);
indx(k)=indx(k)-1;
k=(indy==ny);
indy(k)=indy(k)-1;
ind = indy + ny*(indx-1);

tx = min(1,max(0,(x - xnodes(indx))./dx(indx)));
ty = min(1,max(0,(y - ynodes(indy))./dy(indy)));

A = sparse(
    repmat((1:n)',1,4),
    [ind,ind+1,ind+ny,ind+ny+1],
    [(1-tx).*(1-ty), (1-tx).*ty, tx.*(1-ty), tx.*ty],
    n,
    ngrid
);
  
rhs = z;

smoothparam = params.smoothness;
xyRelativeStiffness = [1;1];
  
[i,j] = meshgrid(1:nx,2:(ny-1));
ind = j(:) + ny*(i(:)-1);
dy1 = dy(j(:)-1)/params.yscale;
dy2 = dy(j(:))/params.yscale;

Areg = sparse(
    repmat(ind,1,3),
    [ind-1,ind,ind+1],
    xyRelativeStiffness(2)*[-2./(dy1.*(dy1+dy2)),
    2./(dy1.*dy2), 
    -2./(dy2.*(dy1+dy2))],
    ngrid,
    ngrid
);

[i,j] = meshgrid(1:nx,2:(ny-1));
ind = j(:) + ny*(i(:)-1);
dy1 = dy(j(:)-1)/params.yscale;
dy2 = dy(j(:))/params.yscale;

Areg = sparse(repmat(ind,1,3),[ind-1,ind,ind+1], ...
xyRelativeStiffness(2)*[-2./(dy1.*(dy1+dy2)), ...
2./(dy1.*dy2), -2./(dy2.*(dy1+dy2))],ngrid,ngrid);

[i,j] = meshgrid(2:(nx-1),1:ny);
ind = j(:) + ny*(i(:)-1);
dx1 = dx(i(:)-1)/params.xscale;
dx2 = dx(i(:))/params.xscale;

Areg = [Areg;sparse(repmat(ind,1,3),[ind-ny,ind,ind+ny], ...
xyRelativeStiffness(1)*[-2./(dx1.*(dx1+dx2)), ...
2./(dx1.*dx2), -2./(dx2.*(dx1+dx2))],ngrid,ngrid)];
    
nreg = size(Areg,1);
NA = norm(A,1);
NR = norm(Areg,1);
A = [A;Areg*(smoothparam*NA/NR)];
rhs = [rhs;zeros(nreg,1)];
zgrid = reshape((A'*A)\(A'*rhs),ny,nx);
```